# How to sort Illuminate Collection by multiple columns in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, laravel

I have a an instance of Laravel's Illuminate Collection. The array contains multiple properties.

I need to be able to sort the collection based on 2 different attributes.

I want to first sort by the attribute that is called "sort" and then by an attribute called "title".

Additionally, I have another collection that I like to sort it by the column "sort" if the value of sort is not null, then shuffle the items that have null for "sort" value.

How can I do this type of sort?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can provide a callback function to `Collection::sort`:

```
$collection->sort(function($a, $b) {
   if($a->sort === $b->sort) {
     if($a->title === $b->title) {
       return 0;
     }
     return $a->title < $b->title ? -1 : 1;
   } 
   return $a->sort < $b->sort ? -1 : 1;
});
```

This is documented [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-sort).

Comment: Thank you for this code. Can you please explain how it works? what would be the values for $b and $b? why are you returning -1 or 1 ?

Comment: This is well documented here: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php#refsect1-function.usort-parameters

Comment: Thank you so much! very helpfull

Answer (score 13):

If you're using PHP 7, you can use the spaceship operator:

```php
$collection->sort(function ($a, $b) {
    return $a->sort === $b->sort ? $a->title <=> $b->title : $a->sort <=> $b->sort;
});
```

The `<=>` symbol is called the spaceship operator (or technically: the combined comparison operator). You can read more about it in [the RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/combined-comparison-operator).

Answer (score 0):

The other answers (and PHP's documentation) were very helpful. After some experimenting, I found you can also sort on related tables as well.

Using the `->with($relatedTableName)` on the collection, and then using the `->sort()` as described, you can sort on a related table field by using:

> ```
> $baseTableField = "tableField"; // Field name from primary table/model
> $relatedTableMapString = "tableName.tableField"; // Field name from a related table
>
> $collection->with('relatedTableName')->sort(function($a, $b) use ($relatedTableMapString, $baseTableField) {
>
>     $relatedTableName = explode(".", $relatedTableMapString)[0];
>     $relatedTableFieldName = explode(".", $relatedTableMapString)[1];
>
>     if($a->$relatedTableName->$relatedTableFieldName === $b->$relatedTableName->$relatedTableFieldName) {
>         if($a->$baseTableField === $b->$baseTableField) {
>             return 0;
>         }
>         return $a->$baseTableField < $b->$baseTableField ? -1 : 1;
>     }
>     return $a->$relatedTableName->$relatedTableFieldName < $b->$relatedTableName->$relatedTableFieldName ? -1 : 1;
> });
> ```